# Sum the values of the inputs of a specific form and display the result

Tags: javascript, forms, input, sum

My page is made of several forms with several inputs called "values[]".
When modifying these inputs in one of the forms, I would like to sum the values and display the result in an other input of the same form called "total".

My html code looks like that:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form_1"> 
    <input type="text" name="values[]" id="value_1_1" onkeyup="sum_values(this)" />
    <input type="text" name="values[]" id="value_1_2" onkeyup="sum_values(this)" />
    [... More inputs with the name "values[]" ]
    <input type="text" name="total" disabled>
</form>

<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form_2">
    <input type="text" name="values[]" id="value_2_1" onkeyup="sum_values(this)" />
    <input type="text" name="values[]" id="value_2_2" onkeyup="sum_values(this)" />
    [... More inputs with the name "values[]" ]
    <input type="text" name="total" disabled>
</form>
```

and my javascript is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sum_values(x){
    var arr = document.getElementById(x.form.id).elements['values[]'];
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById(x.form.id).elements['total'].value = tot;   
}
</script>
```

I was very happy to finally see the first form working, but I then figured out that the second one was not...

Could you help me to understand why ?
I'm a beginner at javascript and I tried to arrange some code I found.
Thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var arr = document.getElementById(x.form.id).value`

Comment: If I'm correct, "x.form.id" gives the id of the whole form. The line you refeer to is supposed to get the inputs with the name "values[]" inside this form (not the whole form).

Comment: Then use `x.id` in place of `x.form.id` , this will surely work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to get all elements within a specific form, you can do so using code similar to the following.  The rest of your code should work fine, except your final result input selector.

```js
var formId = 'form1';
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('#' + formId + ' [name="values[]"]');

var tot=0;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
}
document.querySelector('#' + formId + ' [name="total"]').value = tot;
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="5" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="6" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="8" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="2" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="values[]" value="3" />
  <input type="text" name="total" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: That's perfect, I just had to replace 'form1' by x.form.id. I didn't know this way to access the inputs. Thank you very much !